# Category theory and real closed fields

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, category-theory, real-numbers, ordered-fields

On the [nlab page for real-closed fields](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/real+closed+field), these following statements are made pertaining to their category theoretic nature.

> (1) In fact, the category of real closed fields and order-preserving field homomorphisms is a full subcategory of the category of fields and field homomorphisms.
>
> (2) Theorem. The full inclusion of the category of real closed fields and field homomorphisms to the category of ordered fields and ordered field homomorphisms has a left adjoint.

The latter one has a proof following it, but regardless I am interested in seeing the definitive meaning behind these notions. I checked the given references but didn't find anything in the vein of these statements. I'm interested and can extract good intuition on the matters but I would like if anyone has any good sources concerning the relationship between category theory and real closed fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "the definitive meaning", do you mean translating these statements into less category-theoretic language? The first statement just means that every field homomorphism between real closed fields is automatically order-preserving, which follows immediately from the argument that the order is defined in terms of the field operations.

Comment: Cont: You shouldn't necessarily expect a reference on these matters. Full subcategories whose inclusion admits a left adjoint are a dime a dozen, so there's no reason to expect that a more expansive treatment in this particular context exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I misread the first one in a different context and your comment re-addressed me on that matter. I understand now.

Answer (score 2):

1. A subcategory $\def\c{\mathcal} \c B\subseteq\c A$ is *full*, if it is determined by its objects within $\c A$ so that every arrow $B\to B'$ of $\c A$ with $B,B'\in\c B$ is actually in $\c B$. 
   In this case it means that a field homomorphism between real closed fields preserves the order.
2. The inclusion functor $\c B\hookrightarrow\c A$ has a left adjoint iff $\c B$ is a [reflective subcategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_subcategory) of $\c A$, which means that every object $A\in\c A$ has a *reflection* in $\c B$, which is an arrow $A\to B$ with $B\in\c B$ through which every arrow $A\to B'$ factors through uniquely. 
   Note that the left adjoint is just the reflection functor. 
   In this case, the real closure of an ordered field is its reflection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional property here to that of reflective subcategory which is general enough to be worth mentionning.

-Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category. let $\mathcal{P}$ be a full subcategory of $\mathcal{A}$. For an object $a$ of $\mathcal{A}$, we say that an ordered pair $(f,b)$ where $f$ is an arrow $a \rightarrow b$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is an **extension** of $a$.
We define the category $\mathcal{A}_a$ of extensions of $a$ as that whose objecs are extensions and whose morphisms are commutative triangles between extensions. $\mathcal{A}_{a,\mathcal{P}}$ denotes the full subcategory of $\mathcal{A}_a$ where the codomains in extensions are objects of $\mathcal{P}$.

-Let $P$ be a quality of extensions which is conservatively transitive: if $(f,b)$ is an extends $a$ and $(g,c)$ extends $b$, then $(g \circ f,c)$ satisfies $P$ if and only if both $(f,b)$ and $(g,c)$ do.
We then define the category $\mathcal{A}_{a,P}$ of $P$-extensions of $a$ as the full subcategory of $\mathcal{A}_a$ whose objects are $P$-extensions.

We say that an object of $\mathcal{A}$ is **$P$-maximal** if its $P$-extensions come from isomorphisms.

Then if every object $a$ of $\mathcal{A}$ has a $P$-extension  $(\varphi_a,a_P)$ with codomain $a_P$ in $\mathcal{P}$, and which is initial in $\mathcal{A}_{a,\mathcal{P}}$, then any assignment $a \mapsto (\varphi_a,a_P)$ defines a functor from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{P}$ which is left adjoint to the inclusion $\mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$. This is just the notion of reflective subcategory.

The additional property is that then for every object $a$ of $\mathcal{A}$, $a_P$ is $P$-maximal, that the functor $\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{P}$ is essentially onto the category of $P$-maximal objects of $\mathcal{P}$, and $(\varphi_a,a_P)$ is terminal in $\mathcal{A}_{a,P}$.

For real closure, the relevant property in the category of ordered field is to be an algebraic extension. For ordered rings with injective morphisms, the property of being a degree $1$ extension yields the reflective category of ordered fields and reflective functor of fraction field. For ordered fields with cofinal morphisms, the property of being a dense extension gives the category of Cauchy-complete ordered fields with Cauchy-completion functor.